# Reversing a 2d grid so (0,0) is on the bottom left, instead of top left

Tags: python, tkinter, range

I have a 2d grid, where 0,0 is the top left corner of the grid.  However, I need 0,0 to be the bottom left corner with the y axis increasing bottom to top.

```
for x in range(engine.map_size):
    for y in range(engine.map_size):
        self.columnconfigure(x, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(y, weight=1)
```

(this is inside a tkinter project)

This works fine but as stated, this places 0,0 at the top left corner.  I tried using `range` with `reversed()`, and a `range` starting from `engine.map_size-1` counting down, but that didn't seem to change anything

```
for x in range(engine.map_size):
    for y in range(engine.map_size, -1, -1):
        self.columnconfigure(x, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(y, weight=1)
```

I also tried the way above, which also produced no change

I left the tkinter code in there for context, but essentially I'm just trying to get the y range to descend from map_size to 0.  Not 0 to map_size.  Is range not the right choice here?

Comment: What does `rowconfigure` do? If you want to know the answer in the context of a tkinter project where you want to arrange something in some order, I think that is important information that you should [edit] into your question. A 2d grid (i.e. a list-of-lists) e.g. `grid = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]` can be flipped upside down by simply `reversed(grid)`, but that doesn't seem to be your question

Comment: That is just tkinter code.  Its basically saying that on the y coordinate of that spot on the tkinter grid, will be the y coordinate set in the range.  Which is why i'm trying to get the y range to descend instead of ascend. The answer doesnt need to be, nor should really be affected by the fact that its inside of tkinter.  I believe the answer lies within my understanding of range().  the same result using the same code (without the bottom 2 tkinter lines) would result in the same.  I believe but I could be wrong

Comment: My point is, unless `self.rowconfigure` modifies `self` such that calling `self.rowconfigure(1, weight=1); self.rowconfigure(2, weight=1)` is different than `self.rowconfigure(2 weight=1); self.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)`, simply reversing the order you call `rowconfigure` won't matter.

Comment: The point is, tkinter _ignores_ empty cells, which means if you create a widget in the 100th row and 100th column it will be placed in the 1st row and 1st column if there are no items till the 99th row and 99th column (you could add `min_width` for all rows/columns till 99th row for it to look like it is occupying some space but that is just a hacky way). I don't know if there is a way to change how `grid` does its placing. So the essentially I would ask you to show the UI of how it is right now and how you expect it to be, maybe there is a better way than changing the placement

Answer (score -2, accepted):

if you use the function `reversed(range(engine.map_size))`. that would do the magic!

so your code would looks like:

```
for x in range(engine.map_size):
    for y in reversed(range(engine.map_size)):
        self.columnconfigure(x, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(y, weight=1)
```

Comment: I did try reversed() and it still places my 0,0 in the top left.  Which now leads me to believe  It's possible the issue lies deeper within the code or with tkinter, as another commenter mentioned.  I may have to edit the title and post more relevant code

Comment: Yeah, it's somewhere deeper in the code.  The answer with reversed() did indeed solve the y issue.  But it changes somewhere along the line.  Whelp, onto debugging...

Comment: This wouldn't be any different than what OP has shown. `range(x-1, -1, -1)` is identical to `reversed(range(x))`

Comment: Correct.  I am mistaking in the way I presented the issue.  You were both correct.  The issue lies elsewhere in my code which I didnt realize